# What qr scanner should I use?

Tags: flutter, dart

I whas using: "https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner" but now this package is in "Maintenance Mode Only", what should I use If I want to scan my qr code and think about future development? I do not want to my package to broke one day.

How to make qr code scanner in my app? What to use?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend this package: mobile_scanner: ^2.0.0.
Link for the package: https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner
It's hard to say which package will work "forever". Either you constantly maintain your own app and make sure that it always uses the right QR code scanner package, or you create your own package, which may not always be up-to-date, so you have to spend time on it.

If you want to create your own qr code package, check out these things, maybe they will help. CameraX and AVFoundation.

I hope I helped a little to solve your problem.